# How to make a program loop forever until a certain case in a switch statement is met?

Tags: c++, c++11

How can I make this program loop forever unless the user chooses 'C' in the switch statement? I've tried several things on my own that didn't seem to work and I am not sure how to proceed, since I am still sort of a beginner in C++. Can anyone help? Let me know if you need additional info.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello user, what do you want to do: " << endl
        << "A. Display A Message" << endl
        << "B. Perform A Calculation" << endl
        << "C. Exit The Program" << endl;
    int result = 80 + 10;
    char answer;
    cin >> answer;
    switch (answer)
    {

    case 'A':
        cout << "Welcome to C++!" << endl;
        break;

    case 'B':
        cout << 80 << " + " << 10 << " = " << result << endl;
        break;

    case 'C':
        cout << "Goodbye...." << endl;
        break;
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: *Loop* is the key word.

Comment: I'm seeing a misplaced `return` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Currently your `return 0;` statement is unreachable.)

The simplest way is to use a `for(;;)` infinite loop idiom, and a `return` in the case 'C' case in place of the `break`:

```
for (;;){
    char answer;
    cin >> answer;
    switch (answer){    
    case 'A':
        cout << "Welcome to C++!" << endl;
        break;    
    case 'B':
        cout << 80 << " + " << 10 << " = " << result << endl;
        break;    
    case 'C':
        cout << "Goodbye...." << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The `break` statements take program control out of the `switch` but **not** the loop.

We tend to use `for(;;)` over alternatives such as `while(true)` since many compilers accept the former without a warning.

Comment: Who are “we”, and what compiler gives a warning for `while (true)`? I couldn’t find a single example in Compiler Explorer, and even with `-Weverything` [clang gives no error](https://godbolt.org/g/Br5xn8).

Comment: Old C compilers did. I'm not a young cat, you know. "We" = old cats using ANSI and pre-standardised C. Sorry for not explaning earlier. Looking through all those compilers would be heartbreaking. Feel free to downvote me if you'd find that cathartic!

Comment: Unless there are modern compilers I missed, it’s an outdated idiom which is harder to readable than the modern counterpart without giving any benefit. That’s worth a comment, but it’s nowhere near bad enough for a downvote, especially when you explain what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
bool finished=false;
while (!finished)
  {
  switch (something)
     {
     case foo:
       finished = true; break;
      ...
     }
   }
```

Or one of a dozen ways to achieve the same thing ;)

Comment: But this leaks `finished` into the surrounding scope.

Comment: Sure. Like everything else in programming, you have to balance the costs and benefits of doing one thing over another.

Comment: There is always `while(bool keep_running = true) { /* somewhere in here set it to false */ }` ;)

Comment: Indeed. Mixing assignments with tests like this leads to compact code, but I'm not sure it's always the most readable of constructs. I agree that it's harmless, and idiomatic, in a case like this, though.

Comment: @KevinBoone It's not actually assignment.  It intializes a variable of type `bool` named `keep_running` and checks if it evaluates to `true` on every iteration.  It is the same as `label: { T t = x; if (t) { statement; goto label; } }`

Comment: Fair enough; but I respectfully submit that the distinction is a highly technical one, particularly seen in the context of the OP's question.